# Between process, There is a socket shared through msg. With the socket getpeername results is 0.0.0.0 without any error

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Between process, There is a socket shared through msg. 
With the socket, tryng to get remote connection information.
But getpeername results is 0.0.0.0  without any error.

Even I checked /proc/net/tcp there is no connection.

Here is my detail implementation.

1. For Webserver , lighttpd recevie http connection
2. web server by-pass the accepted socket to a process
3. fcgi program handle the socket (from web server), for simple work.
4. Simultaneously step3. 
   A process receive the shared socket from web server and hanle main procedure

[ In above procedure, Step 3 and 4 works simultaneously
  But step 3 is simple. So Step 3 will be finish instantly, 
  and then web server close a request.
  After that only Step 4 works alone. ]

Except getpeername in a process (step 4), 
all other socket functions fine ; like as select/send/recv

About get peername in a shared socket between process, does not work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK fcgis are spawned at server startup time, not when the first request comes in. So the socket passed to your fcgi cannot be connected to a remote host so `getpeername` cannot return something different than localhost. http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html#S2.2 even states that `getpeername` returns with an error for fcgis.

If that doesn't answer your question I suggest you show some code.

Comment: Then How can I get a peer address in the fast cgi ?
Should I have another method.
Like as get the peer address information in web server
and then pass it to the cgi using send message or pipe